# Windows 7 has a memory leak, having trouble finding the cause

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm pretty sure my computer has a memory leak. It starts up using an abnormal amount of RAM and it gradually gets worse.

Start-up: 2,0 GB
40 min: 3,4 GB
86 min: 3,6 GB
210 min: 5,1 GB

After enough time my screen just turns black and the computer freezes after which I need to manually restart.

During all these screenshots, all that was open was Firefox and a couple of tabs. Other running processes include Razer Synapse, Bitdefender, f.lux, nothing abnormally heavy.
Here are all processes that are running right after startup (Resource Monitor screenshots):
[image]
[image]

I can provide a list of all the processes that start up when my PC boots, but there really aren't that many.

I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium SP1.
I've scanned for viruses with Bitdefender and Malwarebytes.

The only possible cause I can think of is a driver or program I installed a while ago to try and access a phone with a broken screen by displaying the screen on my pc monitor.

I'm not sure if it's relevant and I stopped at a certain point through the process so I'm not sure what I did and didn't install but I figured I might as well mention it.

The problem is that I don't know where I can find a clear list of all drivers I have installed and how to uninstall them.
I did take the time to remove all unused programs from my PC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you suspect a specific device driver is the cause then you should uninstall it.  We expect a fair amount of research and effort before asking for help, you seem to have several ideas, but failed to act on any of them.

Comment: are the driver softwares not listed in control panel? you could use some programs like revo uninstaller..if they exist in you system and you can uninstall them

Comment: Additionally does this problem happen if you boot to safe mode?

Comment: I've removed all programs I don't need from my PC through either control panel or Revo. Someone told me it's not a driver issue though since my Kernel memory wasn't unusual. Either way I can't find a clear and concise list of all drivers, where in control panel would I find this? Is it the same list as all the programs? I'm going to try booting in safe mode now.

Comment: Start by removing the device drivers you have installed and/or use SysInternal tools ( Autoruns ) which allows you to control which drivers are loaded at startup.  You will have to basically, only load the drivers that must be loaded for your PC to work, then backtrack to each optional driver until you find the culprit.  If you can't do that then reinstalling Windows is likely your only alternative.

Comment: post some pictures (at start, some times later) of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: I think it might be Bitdefender causing the problem. I'm going to try what happens when I disable it and report back.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem was Bitdefender, I've switched to Avira and already my RAM usage seems way more normal.

Comment: Will do as soon as I'm 100% sure, haven't had the time to leave my computer on long enough to check if the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Bitdefender, it didn't occur in safe-mode so I looked around in my list of drivers and coincidentally saw a lot of drivers for Bitdefender. After googling the name of the program and the term memory leak I was pretty convinced this was my problem so I've removed it and replaced it with Avira.

Comment: Its not unusual, most of the time, bugs in software like that are because of unpatched Windows installations ( nearly all of the questions similar to this ended being fixed by installing all updates ).